# Converting given string to camel case recursively

Tags: java, recursion

**Basically I want to recursively get this:**

“    pErHaPs I hAVe wRitten a Sentence LiKE this one “

**To look like this:**

“perhapsIHaveWrittenASentenceLikeThisOne”

- n>0 of spaces before, between, and after each word
- any assortment of upper-case and lower-case letters 
  ex: " lIkE  ThIs"

**What I think I understand:**

- Using `string.charAt(i)` to compare the specific character to a space
- Using `Character.isUpperCase()` for case checking

**What I don't understand:**

- How recursion will work to change the string since strings are immutable
- What the base case will be
- how to only uppercase the first letter of every word **after** the first word

**EDIT:**
This is what I have come up with after a few helpful hints:
`public static String toCamelCase(String str) {

```
    if(str.length() == 1) {
        if(str.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            return "";
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    } else if(str.charAt(0) == ' ' && str.length() != 1) {
        if(str.charAt(1) != ' ') {
            return str.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase() + toCamelCase(str.substring(2, str.length()));
        } else {
            return toCamelCase(str.substring(1, str.length()));
        }
    } else if(str.charAt(0) != ' ' && str.length() != 1) {
        if(str.charAt(1) != ' ') {
            return str.substring(0,2).toLowerCase() + toCamelCase(str.substring(2, str.length()));
        } else {
            return str.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + toCamelCase(str.substring(1, str.length()));
        }
    }
    return str;
}`
```

Everything works except the first letter of the first word is also capitalized. How would I make the code exclude the first word when uppercasing first letters of words? Is this possible recursively?

Comment: Why recursion? I'd do this with a fairly simple loop by characters. If a space, skip. If a nonspace after a space, convert to upper case. Else, to lower case.

Comment: You don't need to check the case. You just need to be able to transform to upper or lower case. `Character` has methods to do that

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev its not personal choice, i have to do it this way.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me... So no code for you. Hints, maybe. Here's one. Your base case (the one where the recursion ends) is a string with no spaces.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev that's not correct. The base-case is an empty string (there may be uppercase letters after the last space that need to be converted to lowercase)

Comment: Good point. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There you go with your recursive implementation:

```
public String camelCase(String inputStr) {
   String s = inputStr.toLowerCase();
   String[] arr = s.split(" "); 
   s = arr[0];
   return getCamelCased(s,1,arr);
}

private String getCamelCased(String s, int index, String[] arr) {
   if(index >= arr.length)
        return s;

   String curr = arr[index++];
   s += curr.length()==1?curr.toUpperCase(): 
   (curr.toUpperCase.charAt(0)+curr.substring(1,curr.length()));

   return getCamelCased(s,index,arr);
}
```